# How to access log information for ColdFusion server in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, error-logging

I have Flex front end talking with ColdFusion as the back end. I have to debug my application and need to:

1. Add log support to ColdFusion where I can add my custom messages to log list
2. Access this log at Flex end.

Is it possible? Has anyone tried it before? Please help me with your suggestions ideas on this.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation :

Flex-side :

1. Create custom LogEvent objects that carry an id, a message, any other properties you want to log.
2. Dispatch those events whenever you want to Log an action or system event that occurs
3. Create a LogManager that's in charge of catching these events, and using a Delegate to make a ServiceCall to your ColdFusion services

ColdFusion :

1. Create a Logging service with APIs for listening for any service-calls from the Flex application
2. Save these log events into your database
3. Create a service that the Flex app can call to retrieve LogObjects (or whatever DAO you want)

Flex :

1. Create a LogView (a datagrid / advanced data grid with a column for every log property you want (essentially a mirror of the database log entries)
2. Create a delegate that your LogManager can use to call that Coldfusion Log Service to retrieve these Log Objects

I'm not sure if you're using a framework (Cairngorms, SWIZ, etc.) so my description of these objects is a little more abstract that you could do it all custom, or put it into your existing framework.

I've done this before, for AnalyticsEvents for GoogleAnalytics (worked with ExternalInterface) and with LogEvents for USER actions and SYSTEM actions.